# Build failed while trying to deploy website ( @parcel/transformer-css: Unexpected token '.')

Tags: deployment, build, package.json, web-hosting, parcel

I was trying to deploy a static website using CloudFlare when the build failed :

This is the log :

```
    Cloning repository...
    From https://github.com/The15Coder/SNNN
    * branch            55e8dffa9fe96940dd521b5541866bc2a03393a9 -> FETCH_HEAD

    HEAD is now at 55e8dff Update package.json
    
    
    Success: Finished cloning repository files
    Installing dependencies
    Python version set to 2.7
    v12.18.0 is already installed.
    Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)

2023-02-25T15:43:59.205701Z Started restoring cached build plugins
2023-02-25T15:43:59.220480Z Finished restoring cached build plugins
2023-02-25T15:43:59.683860Z Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
2023-02-25T15:44:03.046860Z Using ruby version 2.7.1
2023-02-25T15:44:03.414022Z Using PHP version 5.6
2023-02-25T15:44:03.584044Z 5.2 is already installed.
2023-02-25T15:44:03.612113Z Using Swift version 5.2
2023-02-25T15:44:03.612723Z Started restoring cached node modules
2023-02-25T15:44:05.471267Z Finished restoring cached node modules
2023-02-25T15:44:05.707256Z Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.14.4
2023-02-25T15:44:06.648259Z npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
2023-02-25T15:44:18.350845Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:18.351169Z > msgpackr-extract@3.0.0 install /opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/msgpackr-extract
2023-02-25T15:44:18.351324Z > node-gyp-build-optional-packages
2023-02-25T15:44:18.351452Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:18.561477Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:18.561783Z > @parcel/watcher@2.1.0 install /opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/@parcel/watcher
2023-02-25T15:44:18.561932Z > node-gyp-build
2023-02-25T15:44:18.562085Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:18.745682Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:18.745996Z > lmdb@2.5.2 install /opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/lmdb
2023-02-25T15:44:18.746331Z > node-gyp-build-optional-packages
2023-02-25T15:44:18.746520Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:18.972494Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:18.972932Z > protobufjs@7.2.2 postinstall /opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/node_modules/protobufjs
2023-02-25T15:44:18.973115Z > node scripts/postinstall
2023-02-25T15:44:18.973278Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:19.085363Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:19.085714Z > protobufjs@6.11.3 postinstall /opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/protobufjs
2023-02-25T15:44:19.085902Z > node scripts/postinstall
2023-02-25T15:44:19.086046Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:19.535524Z npm WARN monopo.vn@1.0.0 No repository field.
2023-02-25T15:44:19.535886Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @lmdb/lmdb-darwin-arm64@2.5.2 (node_modules/@lmdb/lmdb-darwin-arm64):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.536227Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @lmdb/lmdb-darwin-arm64@2.5.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.536450Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm@2.5.2 (node_modules/@lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.536640Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm@2.5.2: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.536779Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @lmdb/lmdb-darwin-x64@2.5.2 (node_modules/@lmdb/lmdb-darwin-x64):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.536926Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @lmdb/lmdb-darwin-x64@2.5.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.537067Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @lmdb/lmdb-win32-x64@2.5.2 (node_modules/@lmdb/lmdb-win32-x64):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.537177Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @lmdb/lmdb-win32-x64@2.5.2: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.537301Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm64@2.5.2 (node_modules/@lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm64):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.537421Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm64@2.5.2: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.537529Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-darwin-arm64@3.0.0 (node_modules/@msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-darwin-arm64):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.537710Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-darwin-arm64@3.0.0: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.537840Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-darwin-x64@3.0.0 (node_modules/@msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-darwin-x64):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.537968Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-darwin-x64@3.0.0: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.538091Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-linux-arm@3.0.0 (node_modules/@msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-linux-arm):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.538203Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-linux-arm@3.0.0: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.538325Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-linux-arm64@3.0.0 (node_modules/@msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-linux-arm64):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.538444Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-linux-arm64@3.0.0: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.538558Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-win32-x64@3.0.0 (node_modules/@msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-win32-x64):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.538664Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-win32-x64@3.0.0: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.538776Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: lightningcss-win32-x64-msvc@1.19.0 (node_modules/lightningcss-win32-x64-msvc):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.538892Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for lightningcss-win32-x64-msvc@1.19.0: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.539051Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: lightningcss-linux-arm64-musl@1.19.0 (node_modules/lightningcss-linux-arm64-musl):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.539164Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for lightningcss-linux-arm64-musl@1.19.0: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.539270Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: lightningcss-linux-arm64-gnu@1.19.0 (node_modules/lightningcss-linux-arm64-gnu):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.539403Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for lightningcss-linux-arm64-gnu@1.19.0: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.539510Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: lightningcss-linux-arm-gnueabihf@1.19.0 (node_modules/lightningcss-linux-arm-gnueabihf):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.539613Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for lightningcss-linux-arm-gnueabihf@1.19.0: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.539725Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: lightningcss-darwin-x64@1.19.0 (node_modules/lightningcss-darwin-x64):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.539830Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for lightningcss-darwin-x64@1.19.0: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.539934Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: lightningcss-darwin-arm64@1.19.0 (node_modules/lightningcss-darwin-arm64):
2023-02-25T15:44:19.540058Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for lightningcss-darwin-arm64@1.19.0: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2023-02-25T15:44:19.540162Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:19.543267Z added 404 packages from 369 contributors and audited 420 packages in 12.931s
2023-02-25T15:44:19.688529Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:19.688845Z 97 packages are looking for funding
2023-02-25T15:44:19.689002Z   run `npm fund` for details
2023-02-25T15:44:19.689142Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:19.689274Z found 0 vulnerabilities
2023-02-25T15:44:19.689397Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:19.732229Z NPM modules installed
2023-02-25T15:44:20.126730Z Installing Hugo 0.54.0
2023-02-25T15:44:20.814641Z Hugo Static Site Generator v0.54.0-B1A82C61A/extended linux/amd64 BuildDate: 2019-02-01T10:04:38Z
2023-02-25T15:44:20.819992Z Started restoring cached go cache
2023-02-25T15:44:20.839804Z Finished restoring cached go cache
2023-02-25T15:44:20.991504Z go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
2023-02-25T15:44:21.006488Z go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
2023-02-25T15:44:21.009397Z Installing missing commands
2023-02-25T15:44:21.009643Z Verify run directory
2023-02-25T15:44:21.009774Z Executing user command: npm run build
2023-02-25T15:44:21.360295Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:21.360614Z > monopo.vn@1.0.0 build /opt/buildhome/repo
2023-02-25T15:44:21.360787Z > parcel index.html
2023-02-25T15:44:21.360925Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:23.748612Z tput: unknown terminal "unknown"
2023-02-25T15:44:23.828031Z Server running at http://localhost:1234
2023-02-25T15:44:23.885829Z Building...
2023-02-25T15:44:24.030507Z  Build failed.
2023-02-25T15:44:24.031893Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:24.032744Z @parcel/transformer-css: Unexpected token '.'
2023-02-25T15:44:24.033294Z 
2023-02-25T15:44:24.037666Z   /opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/lightningcss/node/composeVisitors.js:67
2023-02-25T15:44:24.037851Z         return v?.(item.value);
2023-02-25T15:44:24.037999Z                  ^
2023-02-25T15:44:24.038117Z   
2023-02-25T15:44:24.038225Z   SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
2023-02-25T15:44:24.038335Z       at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
2023-02-25T15:44:24.038460Z       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
2023-02-25T15:44:24.038572Z       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
2023-02-25T15:44:24.038678Z       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
2023-02-25T15:44:24.038783Z       at NodePackageManager.load 
2023-02-25T15:44:24.038888Z   (/opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/@parcel/package-manager/lib/index.js:3375:15)
2023-02-25T15:44:24.039009Z       at NodePackageManager.requireSync 
2023-02-25T15:44:24.039117Z   (/opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/@parcel/package-manager/lib/index.js:3353:21)
2023-02-25T15:44:24.039223Z       at Module.m.require 
2023-02-25T15:44:24.039331Z   (/opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/@parcel/package-manager/lib/index.js:3366:25)
2023-02-25T15:44:24.039446Z       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2023-02-25T15:44:24.039557Z       at Object.<anonymous> 
2023-02-25T15:44:24.039671Z   (/opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/lightningcss/node/index.js:26:34)
2023-02-25T15:44:24.039787Z       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
2023-02-25T15:44:24.039904Z
```

This is my project :
[Noise Shader effect](https://github.com/The15Coder/NoiseShaderOvitame-NPM)

I don't know why the build is always failing when i try to publish my website in a web hosting website like cloudflare

this is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "monopo.vn",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Monopo clone",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel index.html",
    "start": "parcel index.html"
  },
  "author": "Jason",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.17.1",
    "gsap": "^3.10.4",
    "lil-gui": "^0.17.0",
    "three": "^0.142.0",
    "wrangler": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cloudflare/workers-types": "^4.20230221.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-glsl": "^2.8.3",
    "buffer": "^5.7.1",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "parcel": "^2.8.3",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "punycode": "^1.4.1",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

And this is my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Three js</title>
    <style>
        *{margin:0;padding:0} 
        canvas{display: block}
        #container{width: 100vw;height: 100vh}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="./js/app.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be an issue with your node version. Mine also failed and I found out that the node version was **node v12.18.0**.

Try upgrading it to **v14.x.x** and see if it works.

related github [issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/8749).